# How to detect infinity loops?

Tags: anylogic

is there any way to detect infinity loops in the code of an anylogic model.
Example:
create_MyDynamicEvent1(0.0) -> invoked method calls again -> create_MyDynamicEvent1(0.0)
Thanks!

Comment: You should more explain, progarm languge, picture and so on.

Comment: anylogic is using java 8

Answer (score 0):

Usually you will get informed by...stack overflow exception! :)
I don't know what is your technology by if you have an infinite loop you most probably end your available RAM pretty soon so you will notice it.

If you have a logging system of some sort, you can log to debug and view the file exploding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check before running out of memory, simply add variable `counter` (int). In your Dynamic event, add to it using `counter++` and check if it gets unreasonably high.